# Javascript time issue

Tags: javascript, time

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currenttime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time()) ?>'
var montharray=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)

function padlength(what){
var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what
return output
}

function displaytime(){
serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)
var datestring=montharray[serverdate.getMonth()]+" "+padlength(serverdate.getDate())+", "+serverdate.getFullYear()
var timestring=padlength(serverdate.getHours()+1)+":"+padlength(serverdate.getMinutes())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getSeconds())
var minleft=60-serverdate.getMinutes()
var secleft=60-serverdate.getSeconds()
var houleft=24-serverdate.getHours()+1
var newenergyin=padlength(minleft)+":"+padlength(secleft)
var gainin=padlength(houleft)+":"+padlength(minleft)+":"+padlength(secleft)
document.getElementById("servertime").innerHTML=timestring
document.getElementById("moreenergy").innerHTML=newenergyin
document.getElementById("inter").innerHTML=gainin
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("displaytime()", 1000)
}
</script>
```

I am having an issue with the

```
document.getElementById("inter").innerHTML=gainin
```

part of the code. If I do

```
<span id='inter'></span>
```

it doesn't want to work, but the previous one I made with

```
document.getElementById("moreenergy").innerHTML=newenergyin
```

works absolutely fine.

What am I doing wrong?! All I want is to show a countdown to midnight, the countdown till the next hour works fine :S

HTML:

```
<td><center><b>- Currency -</b></center>Credits: <a href='main.php?id=depcre'>0</a>    
<br>Platinum: <font color='orange'>46</font><br>Waste Magic: <font color='orange'>48</font>    
<br>Copper: <font color='orange'>49</font><br>Silver: <font color='orange'>48</font>    
<br>Gold: <font color='orange'>47</font><br><br>Bank: <a href='main.php?id=witcre'>841</a>    
<Small> (<font color='orange'>0.25%</font> IGDA)</small><br>Interest Gain In: <font     color='orange'><span id='inter'></span></font></td>
```

OK, Entire HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currenttime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time()) ?>'
var montharray=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)

function padlength(what){
var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what
return output
}

function displaytime(){
serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)
var datestring=montharray[serverdate.getMonth()]+" "+padlength(serverdate.getDate())+", "+serverdate.getFullYear()
var timestring=padlength(serverdate.getHours()+1)+":"+padlength(serverdate.getMinutes())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getSeconds())
var minleft=60-serverdate.getMinutes()
var secleft=60-serverdate.getSeconds()
var houleft=24-serverdate.getHours()+1
var newenergyin=padlength(minleft)+":"+padlength(secleft)
var gainin=padlength(houleft)+":"+padlength(minleft)+":"+padlength(secleft)
document.getElementById("servertime").innerHTML=timestring
document.getElementById("moreenergy").innerHTML=newenergyin
document.getElementById("inter").innerHTML=gainin
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("displaytime()", 1000)
}

</script>
    <tr>
        <td><center><b>- Stats [<a href='main.php?id=<?php echo $page;?>'>Refresh</a>] -</b></center>Level: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_LEVL]; ?></font><br>Experience: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_CUREXP]; ?></font>/<font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_NEXEXP]; ?></font><br>Energy: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_CURENG]; ?></font>/<font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_NEXENG]; ?></font><br>Skill: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_SKILL]; ?></font><br>HP: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_CURHP]; ?></font>/<font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_MAXHP]; ?></font><br>Hit Rate: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_HITRATE]; ?></font><br>
<?php
$cureng = $GETVAR['PL_CURENG'];
$nexeng = $GETVAR['PL_NEXENG'];
$curhit = $GETVAR['PL_CURHP'];
$maxhit = $GETVAR['PL_MAXHP'];
if(($cureng == $nexeng) && ($curhit == $maxhit))
{
    echo "<br>";
}else
{
    echo "Energy and HP Increase in: <font color='orange'><span id='moreenergy'></span>    </font>";
}


?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><b>- Currency -</b></center>Credits: <a href='main.php?    id=depcre'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_CRED]; ?></a><br>Platinum: <font color='orange'><?php echo     $GETVAR[PL_PLAT]; ?></font><br>Waste Magic: <font color='orange'><?php echo     $GETVAR[PL_WAMA]; ?></font><br>Copper: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_COPP]; ?>    </font><br>Silver: <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_SILV]; ?></font><br>Gold:     <font color='orange'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_GOLD]; ?></font><br><br>Bank: <a href='main.php?    id=witcre'><?php echo $GETVAR[PL_BANK]; ?></a><Small> (<font color='orange'><?php echo     $GETVAR[PL_INTR]*10;?>%</font> IGDA)</small><br>Interest Gain In: <font color='orange'>    <span id='inter'></span></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><b>- You -</b></center>
                <a href='main.php?id=news'>News</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=yourhome'>Your Home</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=yourmage'>Your Mage</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=puppets'>Your Puppets</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=enchants'>Your Enchants</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=clan'>Your Clan</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=pm'>Mailbox</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=100%>    <center><b>- Navigation -</b></center>
                <a href='main.php?id=townarea'>Town of Tolbart</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=skilupgr'>Skill Upgrades</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=colloseu'>Colloseum</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=wastmagi'>Waste Magic Center</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=field'>Field</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=market'>Market</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=gather'>Gathering</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=darkmagi'>Dark Magic Workshop</a><br>
                <a href='main.php?id=research'>Research Facility</a><br>    <br>
                <a href='main.php?id=logout'>Log Out</a>

<br>Game Time: <span class="servertime" id="servertime"></span>
</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Easier to help if you describe *what* the issue is, and include any JS console info.

Comment: what happen when you do the reverse: `document.getElementById("inter").innerHTML=newenergyin` and `document.getElementById("moreenergy").innerHTML=gainin` ?

Comment: Some sample HTML markup (that this script interacts with) wouldn't hurt either :)

Comment: Im not sure how to get JS console info, It's not displaying anything in the Span at all which is the issue I have at the moment.

Comment: I'm getting this in chomes console log

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    displaytime
    (anonymous function)

Comment: added on the end of the post.

Comment: There's no `moreenergy` in your HTML.

Comment: Ok... it works if the moreenergy one is visible... I have some PHP code that doesn't show the moreenergy one if the persons energy and hp are at maximum. So I am guessing it must have something to do with that.

Comment: I think it errors on trying to find moreenergy and stops running the javascript if it can't find it. I have it working although it still gives me console errors

Comment: I managed to fix this buy placing a PHP check within the Javascript to ensure that the span id was actually visible to the page. 

Thanks for your help guys!

    <?php
    $cureng = $GETVAR['PL_CURENG'];
    $nexeng = $GETVAR['PL_NEXENG'];
    $curhit = $GETVAR['PL_CURHP'];
    $maxhit = $GETVAR['PL_MAXHP'];
    if(($cureng == $nexeng) && ($curhit == $maxhit))
    {}else
    {
    echo 'document.getElementById("moreenergy").innerHTML=newenergyin';
    }?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed all the php from the question to make it more simple. It seems that your java script runs fine.

You can see it running on [my js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/actionCat/UTahf/)

NOTE:

You can you the javascript Date() class instead of getting the date from php.

Also try not to use a string in setInterval (setinterval uses eval on the string). Trying using the following instead

> setInterval(function(){displaytime()}, 1000)

Comment: I use PHP to get the server time instead of the local time, Since Javascript is client side, it will only pick up local time, correct me if im wrong.

Comment: That seems correct. Did you get  to the bottom of your problem in the end?